# Laravel Notification duplicate error with more than one notification via (database,email)

Tags: laravel

I have more than 1500 users and sending them a notification via Mail and Database to remind them something every week using cron and supervisor.

My queue config:

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 90,
],
```

My Supervisor config:

```
[program:run-cron]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/projectName/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3  --timeout=50 --queue=default,reminder
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=6
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/projectName/storage/logs/supervisor.log
```

Code at notification:

```
class UserReminderNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $job,$days,$settings;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->queue="reminder";
        $this->user = $data['user'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return array('database','mail');
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $title = 'Reminder Title';

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject($title)
            ->view(
                'user.reminder',
                array(
                    'user' => $this->user,
                )
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'type' => 'user',
            'name' => $this->user->name,
            'messsage' => 'Reminder message';
        ];
    }
}
```

Error What I am getting at failed job:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3fee38fc-8e1f-4212-9e96-12c4af1510c4' for key 'PRIMARY'

What I am missing.retry_after is already greater than --timeout as you can see.

I think on mail failing,when supervisor try once again at that time it again do entry for that database notification.Weird is that,it is not coming for all.

Comment: Sorry for my non-contribution into this issue but, have you found out a solution?

Comment: @CesarSantana still not any luck.

Comment: Any solution to this problem yet?

Comment: We need to see where the notification is being dispatched. The error you're getting relates to a UUID issue. The default failed_jobs table in Lavravel doesn't use UUID as primary key, so which table exactly is generating the error?